# R Studio doesn't react to Run All

Tags: r, rstudio

In R studio, I used to be able to click "run all" and it would run the script without any problem, so I could work with the output.

Now, when I open the file again and try to run the script, nothing happens, even though I haven't made any changes ( I think ). No error messages are shown.

How could I go about this?

Comment: Any error message displayed? Or do you change anything in R Studio configuration/setting?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: No it doesn't show any error message. I haven't changed anything in the configuration/setting either (at least not on purpose). 
In the bottom right it says R Markdown, which it has always been. If I change it to R Script, then the Script runs but it shows many error messages that never have been shown when using R Markdown.

Comment: I re-downloaded RStudio and opened the original script which used to run without any problems. Still RStudio doesn't do anything when asked to run the script.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks, had the same problem.  Super frustrating!  In the end "Run All" was not working because the last chunk did not have [```] at the end.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Reset Rstudio state by renaming ~/.local/share/rstudio to ~/.local/share/rstudio.old. It will automatically create a new folder. Relaunch

Older versions might be  ~/.local/share/rstudio-desktop

I was banging my head on the wall and the original answer provided here didn't work, but changing the folder name did.